# Can an edge disjoint decomposition $G_1,G_2,\ldots ,G_k$ of a complete graph $K_n$ in complete bipartite graph be "Star-less"?

Tags: graph-theory

I was looking for a combinatorial proof of the fact that if $G_1,G_2,\ldots ,G_k$ be an edge disjoint decomposition of the complete graph $K_n$, then $k\geq n-1$. Doing the proof, the problem boils down to this.

**Let $G_1,G_2,\ldots ,G_k$ be an edge disjoint decomposition of the complete graph $K_n$ such that each $G_i$ is complete bipartite. Is it always the case that at least one $G_i$ must be a star($K_{1,r}$)?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my question.

Comment: I don't understand the original question. $K_n$ denotes a complete graph, not a complete bipartite graph. Did you mean that the $G_i$ must all be all complete bipartite graphs (for involved vertices) as you later mention in your "boil-down" section? Also I don't see that you are headed in a particularly "combinatorial" direction.

Comment: Yes each $G_i$ needs to be complete bipartite. I just want to know whether this property that "each such collection of $G_i$s always contains a star" is true or not.

Comment: As mentioned by Joffan, "complete bipartite graph $K_n$" makes no sense. It is either "complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$'' or "complete graph $K_n$''.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. Edited.

Comment: I just realized you're trying to find another way to the [Graham-Pollak result](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%E2%80%93Pollak_theorem). Good luck, but as you see, avoiding star graphs is not going to give you the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $H \cong K_9$ on the vertices $\{\,1, 2, \ldots, 9\,\}$ and the following $4$-cycles:
$$12341, 45674, 78917, 13581, 24682, 36973, 38493, 27592, 15261.$$
It is easy to check that each edge of $H$ belongs to exactly one of these $4$-cycles. And yes, every $4$-cycle is bipartite.

---

This example can be modified a bit to have $8 = 9 - 1$ bicliques. Let $G_1 = K_{4, 2}$ with parts $\{\,1, 2, 3, 4\,\}$ and $\{\,5, 6\,\}$. Other $G_i$ are still $4$-cycles:
$$12341, 13981, 17591, 24972, 28692, 37483, 56785.$$

Comment: To be precise, the answer to the question in the body is no; the answer to the question in the title is yes.

Comment: Thanks .... Can you say the same thing when k=n-1?

Comment: @KaustavPaul I've added another example